# Issue with 0x quote api

Tags: 0x

I am calling the quote api, and when passing its response to ethereum.request() for making a transaction, MetaMask pops up a very high tx fees- 1.89 BNB! which is way too high fees for this basic swap function.

Just to add this is in bsc network, and I'm swapping from USDT to BEP20 custom token.

Can someone please help here.

API URL: `https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955&buyToken=0xaf3889ba617ac973b358513d9031778d2bc783df&sellAmount=1000000000000000000&slippagePercentage=0.10&takerAddress=0x06125e1457f833E29D5aebAaCdF8eED8A6Febaee`

Response:

```
{
    "chainId": 56,
    "price": "1548581.394730707",
    "guaranteedPrice": "1393723.255257636",
    "estimatedPriceImpact": null,
    "to": "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
    "data": "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",
    "value": "0",
    "gas": "543981",
    "estimatedGas": "543981",
    "from": "0x06125e1457f833e29d5aebaacdf8eed8a6febaee",
    "gasPrice": "5000000000",
    "protocolFee": "0",
    "minimumProtocolFee": "0",
    "buyTokenAddress": "0xaf3889ba617ac973b358513d9031778d2bc783df",
    "sellTokenAddress": "0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955",
    "buyAmount": "1548581394730707",
    "sellAmount": "1000000000000000000",
    "sources": [
        {
            "name": "BakerySwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Belt",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "DODO",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "DODO_V2",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ellipsis",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mooniswap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "MultiHop",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nerve",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Synapse",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "PancakeSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "PancakeSwap_V2",
            "proportion": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "SushiSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Smoothy",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "ApeSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "CafeSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "CheeseSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "JulSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "LiquidityProvider",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "WaultSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "FirebirdOneSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "JetSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "ACryptoS",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "KyberDMM",
            "proportion": "0"
        }
    ],
    "orders": [
        {
            "makerToken": "0xaf3889ba617ac973b358513d9031778d2bc783df",
            "takerToken": "0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955",
            "makerAmount": "1548581394730707",
            "takerAmount": "1000000000000000000",
            "fillData": {
                "tokenAddressPath": [
                    "0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955",
                    "0xaf3889ba617ac973b358513d9031778d2bc783df"
                ],
                "router": "0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e"
            },
            "source": "PancakeSwap_V2",
            "sourcePathId": "0x7fd9558bff4261870d22f918a3aac9c40a582fa7aa7d561d29dd84f4ae1339aa",
            "type": 0
        }
    ],
    "allowanceTarget": "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
    "sellTokenToEthRate": "379.528873271830081228",
    "buyTokenToEthRate": "0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely your transaction is failing and Metamask incorrectly calculates the gas as the entire blocks gas.

Looking at the output here I can currently see it is producing an error, https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955&buyToken=0xaf3889ba617ac973b358513d9031778d2bc783df&sellAmount=1000000000000000000&slippagePercentage=0.10&takerAddress=0x06125e1457f833E29D5aebAaCdF8eED8A6Febaee

```
{
    code: 105,
    reason: "IncompleteTransformERC20Error",
    values: {
        outputToken: "0xaf3889ba617ac973b358513d9031778d2bc783df",
        outputTokenAmount: "1373091610763976",
        minOutputTokenAmount: "1398576787535538"
    }
}
```

At this time 0xAPI only works with standard ERC20/BEP20 tokens which does not include tokens (like SHIBIC) that take a fee on transfer.